# JQuery - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined in Google Geocoding

Tags: jquery, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to use reverse-geocoding in Laravel-5.8

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function GetAddress() {
    var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtLat").value);
    var lng = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtLong").value);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
      'latLng': latlng
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
          $("#myaddress").results[1].formatted_address;
        }
      }
    });
  } <
  /script>
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Get Address" onclick="GetAddress()" />

<input type="hidden" id="txtLat" value="{{ $currentLocationFilter[0] ?? '' }}" readonly/>
<input type="hidden" id="txtLong" value="{{ $currentLocationFilter[1] ?? '' }}" disabled/>

<input type="text" id="myaddress" value="0" disabled>
```

GetAddress(), I want to display the result in myaddress but I got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

and it points to:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

This works:

```
alert("Location: " + results[1].formatted_address);
```

but I don't want to use alert

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The line of code throwing the error is attempting to access a property of a jQuery object, `results`, which does not exist; hence the error you see.

From the context of the `alert()` which you state is working, it would appear that you're trying to set the value within the `#myaddress` element. As such, use the `val()` method of the jQuery object to set the value of the target `input` element:

```
$("#myaddress").val(results[1].formatted_address);
```

Here's a complete example, with the inline event handlers removed as they are no longer good practice and should not be used.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#get-address').on('click', () => {
    var lat = parseFloat($("#txtLat").val());
    var lng = parseFloat($("#txtLong").val());
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
      latLng latlng
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
          $("#myaddress").val(results[1].formatted_address);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Get Address" id="get-address" />
<input type="hidden" id="txtLat" value="{{ $currentLocationFilter[0] ?? '' }}" readonly/>
<input type="hidden" id="txtLong" value="{{ $currentLocationFilter[1] ?? '' }}" disabled/>
<input type="text" id="myaddress" value="0" disabled>
```